# Are there any disadvantages to Service Bus queues larger than 1 GB?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Currently my queues are 1 GB (I'm guessing this is the default) and I noticed the documentation says this can go up to 5 GB:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas

I can't find any disadvantage to a higher max queue size and want to make sure I haven't missed anything before switching. I don't see any mention of pricing differences, performance, etc. Does such a disadvantage exist? It seems odd the default wouldn't be 5 GB if there were no drawbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no performance impact or price since it's included in your service tier.
While I can't answer why the default is not set to 1GB, you can always clarify with the Azure Service Bus in [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues).

And remember, a happy queue is an empty queue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As far as the "happy queue" goes, I guess I didn't explain my use case. Rarely, I need to reprocess all of our records (millions) which won't all fit into a 1 GB queue. During normal day-to-day operations, the queue only gets small, frequent bursts of activity :)

Comment: In that case, 5GB should be set to avoid sporadic overflow when you have that burst. It won't cost you more than you'd pay for 1GB.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping! Thanks much.